# How do you set MaterialButton icon size to fit the constraints?

Tags: android, material-design, materialbutton

I have a `MaterialButton` constrained on every side and want to fit a vector icon to those constraints so that it expands or contracts based on the button constraints.

These are the basic attributes:

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:icon="@drawable/icon_name"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="view1"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="view2"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="view3"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="view4" />
```

I have tried the following:

> These are static dimensions based on screen size, so they don't scale.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    android:scaleX="3F"
    android:scaleY="3F" />
```

> This displays the image in its original size.

```
<com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
    app:iconSize="0dp" />
```

- I cannot use `android:foreground` because I am supporting versions lower than API 23.
- I cannot place an image in `android:background` because it breaks `MaterialButton`'s functionality, as stated in the official documents.
- I don't know the purpose of the `android:drawable...` options. There's no way to resize those in xml and they don't have a drawableCenter option.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand but I think what you're trying to do directly contradicts guidelines from the Material Design so you really should just make your own implementation of a Button and not use the `MaterialButton` class. It's written specifically in a way which enforces you to abide by the design rules.

Comment: you can use constraints only inside ConstraintLayout